# Replacing a value in an associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have this:

```
foreach ($books as $book)
{
    $catname = get_category_name($book['category']);
    $book['category'] = $catname;
}
print_r($books);
```

Right now, `$book['category']` represents an integer value, which references the ID of a row in a category table of the database (e.g. ID 1 = Fiction). As you can guess, `get_category_name($id)` takes an ID and finds the correct row, and returns the name of the category. The function works correctly, and if i `print_r($catname)` in the `foreach` it prints the names of the categories, like it should.

I have an associative array called `$books` that gets filled from every row in the book table in the database. What I want to do, is take the category integer value of each book element and use `get_category_name($id)` to replace that integer value with the actual category name.

The problem I am having is that I cannot replace the integer value that already exists at `$book['category']` with the actual category name which resides in `$catname`. When I use `print_r($books)` to see if the changes were made in the `foreach`, they confirm the changes do not get made.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this?

```
foreach ($books as &$book)
{
    $catname = get_category_name($book['category']);
    $book['category'] = $catname;
}
print_r($books);
```

Notice the &$book.

Answer (score 2):

You either use `foreach($books as &$book)` and edit `$book`. This way you have a reference to the real book element inside the array in stead of a copy of it. Beware that if you want to do this multiple times on the same array, you will need to reset the array each time after use. See: https://www.php.net/reset

Or you use `foreach($books as $key=>$value)` and edit `$books[$key]`. This way you get copies of the books and their keys. But you then use the key on the original array.

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is that in fact you do not change `$books` but `$book`, that is why you cant see changes in `$books`. Possible solution:

```
foreach ($books as $booksId => $book) //$booksId will contain current index in $books
{
    $catname = get_category_name($book['category']);
// now you can change correct index in $books:
    $books[$booksId]['category'] = $catname;
}
```

Edit: @Cardinal solution with refference is also correct.